# Impala shell - Hive Beeline - "Argument list too long"

Tags: shell, hive, impala

I have a Cloudera cluster on which multiple impala jobs are running all the time (i.e. cronjobs containing impala-shell commands). However I have a few INSERT INTO queries that are unusually long: they contain a lot of 'CASE...WHEN...THEN' lines. When these queries are run in impala-shell the command fails with an error "Argument list too long". They run just fine in Hue, but can't get them to run on the commandline.
Are there any workarounds for this?

I've tried running the command via Hive beeline (instead of impala) and setting 'hive.script.operator.truncate.env = true'. Beeline failed with the same error. I've tried if calling the query from a separate file made any difference (it doesn't). Can I save the 'CASE...WHEN...THEN' lines in separate vars perhaps (using 'set') and call those in the query? Or would that be another dead-end? A colleague mentioned a User Defined Function (UDF) might help, but I'm not sure. Opinions?

Comment: Is it the number of _lines_ that causes the error, or the number of _expressions_ in SELECT, or the number of _characters_ in the query? To begin with, if you remove the EOL chars from your "separate file", does it make a difference? (`cat xxx.hql | tr '\r\n' '  ' > xxx-oneliner.hql`)

Comment: Are you sure this is not a crontab limitation?  https://serverfault.com/questions/546342/crontab-maximum-command-length

Comment: The error shows up outside of crontab use as well. As for length, the number of newlines isn't the issue.

Comment: on your host where you run impala-shell, what does getconf ARG_MAX show and how big is your query in bytes?  Another thing to look at is: xargs --show-limits < /dev/null.  https://superuser.com/questions/705928/compile-the-kernel-to-increase-the-command-line-max-length

Comment: ARG_MAX=2097152, xargs --show-limits=2090564 (max length), 131072 (actually used). Query-file= 158720 (=155kb). So my guess would be to double 'actually used' with xargs -s 262144, but it just seems to ignore that and still returns the same error.